# Numpy astype not working when replacing values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array of integers and would like to replace some values with nans. That requires converting the type to floats and if I did the naive:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
# 1)
x = x.astype(float)[x==2]=np.nan
# 2) this does not change the values inside x
# x.astype(float)[x==2]=np.nan
```

I got

```py
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

in the *1)* case and no change in the *2)*. Everything works if I redefine the `x` type before:

```py
x = np.arange(5)
x = x.astype(float)
x[x==2]=np.nan
# array([ 0.,  1., nan,  3.,  4.])
```

What is going on here? I think that the error message is referring to the `np.nan` but then I have no clue what's going on.

EDIT:
How could I write it without the redefinition, ie. in one line?

Comment: `x.astype(float)` _returns_ a x as floats, which you can then assign to something (in your case you overwrite the existing x with `x = x.astype(float)`). `x[x==2] = np.nan` assigns nans to certain values of an _existing_ array, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: to do in one line what you expect, you could use `x = np.where(x==2, np.nan, x.astype(float))` - [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: So why does the first ```x.astype(float)``` not return ```x``` to be then sliced/indexed and followingly replaced by ```np.nan```? Otherwise thank you both for your comments, that's exactly what I was needing.

Comment: `x.astype(float)` produces a new array, not a `view`.  Modifying it will not modify `x` (the original array).  Don't reassign values to `x=....`; that just confuses you.  Use a new variable name (at least until you have a good handle on how Python handles variables and objects).  And one-liners are not a virtue in Python, especially using `numpy`.

Comment: Does anyone of you want to write it as an answer? Because all three of your comments make part of the answer so I'd put them together but I do not want to take the chances from you. And Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd summarise all the responses from comments from @Swier, @MrFuppes and @hpaulj which answered the issue.

`x.astype(float)` produces a new array, not a view -- it returns `x` as floats, which can then be assigned to something else (in my example I overwrite the existing `x` with `x = x.astype(float)`).

On the other hand, `x[x==2] = np.nan` assigns nans to certain values of an existing array, it doesn't return anything. Modifying it will not modify the original array `x`.

To do what I wanted in one line, one can use `np.where`:

```py
x = np.where(x==2, np.nan, x.astype(float))
```